# Looping data into a function

Tags: r

the following code is something I use for making gambling predictions, part one is what I use to scrape results and fixtures and part two is what I use to actually make the predictions. The bit I'm curious about is, actually in part two of the code.

```
Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters,"Augsburg","Freiburg")
ResultProbabilities<- ResultProbs(Probabilities)
ResultProbabilities
cat("\nHome Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$HomeWin)
cat("\nDraw:", 100/ResultProbabilities$Draw)
cat("\nAway Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$AwayWin)
```

Instead of manually entering football teams, as seen by "Augsburg" and "Freiburg" in the example. Is it possible to pull the data from "Fix" specifically the 6 fixtures when running head(Fix) so in this example it would be

```
        X1                 X2    X3                  X4 X5
      1 05.10.2018 Werder Bremen 18:30           Wolfsburg NA
      2 06.10.2018 Mainz 05      13:30          Hertha BSC NA
      3 06.10.2018 Hannover 96   13:30           Stuttgart NA
      4 06.10.2018 Borussia Dortmund 13:30            Augsburg NA
      5 06.10.2018 Fortuna Düsseldorf 13:30          Schalke 04 NA
      6 06.10.2018 Bayern München 16:30 Borussia M'gladbach NA
```

Is there something I can do to run them all at the same time instead of manually entering each team? I just need the teams from X2 and X4 to go where "Augsburg" and "Freiburg" are.

Code part 1.

```
      library(rvest)
      library(stringr)
      library(plyr)
      library(dplyr)
      library(ggvis)
      library(knitr)
      library(XML)
      library(tidyr)

      url <- "https://www.betstudy.com/soccer-stats/c/portugal/primeira-liga//d/results/"
      webpage <- read_html(url)
      fixtures <- "http://www.betstudy.com/soccer-stats/c/portugal/primeira-liga//d/fixtures/"
      wpfix <- read_html(fixtures)
      fixtable <- html_nodes(wpfix, 'table')
      Fix <- html_table(fixtable)[[2]]
      Champ_Table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
      Champ<- html_table(Champ_Table,fill = TRUE)[[2]]

      names(Champ) <- c("Date", "HomeTeam", "Score"," AwayTeam", "delete")
      Champ$delete <- NULL
      head(Champ)

      Champ <- Champ[!grepl('Pstp',Champ$Score),]
      Champ$Date <- NULL
      Champ <- separate(Champ,Score, into = c("FTHG", "FTAG"), sep="-")
      Champ <- Champ[,c(1,4,2,3)]
      write.csv(Champ, file="AUS")
      head(Champ)
      names(Champ) <- c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTHG", "FTAG")
      head(Fix)

    Head(Champ)
    Head(Fix)
```

Part 1 of the code scrapes results (Champ) and Fixtures (Fix) from whichever league is in the URL.

Code Part 2.

```
    library("vcd")
    source("http://www.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~voss/projects/2010-sports/Football.R")

    results0 <- read.csv("AUS",stringsAsFactors = F) 
    results0$X <- NULL
    results0$X.1 <- NULL
    results0$NA. <- NULL
    results0
    names(results0)<- c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTHG", "FTAG")
    head(results0)
    Parameters(results0)
    countres <- results0$FTHG + results0$FTAG
    table(countres)
    tg <- countres
    fretabtg<-table(tg)
    fretabtg

    gf <- goodfit(fretabtg, type="poisson", method="ML")
    gf
    summary(gf)

    Table0 <- Table(results0)
    Table0
    mean(results0[,3])
    mean(results0[,4])
    var(results0[,3])
    var(results0[,4])
    games <- results0
    g <- nrow(games)
    Y <- matrix(0,2*g,1)
    for (i in 1:g) {
    Y[((2*i)-1)] <- games[i,3]
    Y[(2*i)] <- games[i,4]
    }

    teams <- sort(unique(c(games[,1], games[,2])), decreasing = FALSE) 
    n <- length(teams) 
    X <- matrix(0,2*g,((2*n)+1))
    for (i in 1:g) { 
    M <- which(teams == games[i,1]) 
    N <- which(teams == games[i,2]) 
    X[((2*i)-1),M] <- 1 
    X[((2*i)-1),N+n] <- -1 
    X[(2*i),N] <- 1 
    X[(2*i),M+n] <- -1 
    X[((2*i)-1),((2*n)+1)] <- 1 
    }

    x <- qr(X)
    x$rank
    XX <- X[,-1]
    glm(formula = Y ~ 0 + XX, family = poisson)


    TeamParameters <- Parameters(results0)
    TeamParameters



    SimSeason <- Games(TeamParameters)
    SimSeason

    SimTable <- Table(SimSeason)
    SimTable

    Simulations <- Sim(TeamParameters,3)
    Simulations

    Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters,"Augsburg","Freiburg")
    ResultProbabilities<- ResultProbs(Probabilities)
    ResultProbabilities
    cat("\nHome Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$HomeWin)
    cat("\nDraw:", 100/ResultProbabilities$Draw)
    cat("\nAway Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$AwayWin)
```

Part 2 of the code is used for making the probabilities.

Comment: Where does the very first block of code that you hard code the football teams requiring a loop solution come in Part 2?

Comment: Thanks, your solution did what I was after. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `Map` to iterate elementwise between `Fix$X2` and `Fix$X4` teams. Below prints the `cat` calls and saves each *ResultProbabilities* to a list:

```
run_probs <- function(h_team, a_team) {
   Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters, h_team, a_team)
   ResultProbabilities <- ResultProbs(Probabilities)

   cat(paste("\n", h_team, "VS", a_team))
   cat("\nHome Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$HomeWin)
   cat("\nDraw:", 100/ResultProbabilities$Draw)
   cat("\nAway Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$AwayWin)  

   return(ResultProbabilities)
}

prob_list <- Map(run_probs, Fix$X2, Fix$X4)
```